# Scraping YouTube links from a webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, youtube, screen-scraping

I've been trying to scrape YouTube links from a webpage, but nothing has worked.
This is a picture of what I've been trying to scrape.:
[image: This is a picture of what I've been trying to scrape.]

This is the code I tried most recently:

```
youtube_link = soup.find("a", class_="ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink")
```

And this is the link to the website the YouTube link is in: https://www.electronic-festivals.com/event/i-am-hardstyle-germany

Comment: `but nothing has worked` - what error do you have?

Comment: I got it to work now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the youtube links are within an `iframe` and javascript also needs to run. Try using selenium. The following extracts any `src` or `href` containing `youtub`e. I only enter the key iframe hosting the youtube clip. You could loop all `iframes` checking.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def addItems(links, final):
    for link in links:
        ref = link.get_attribute('src') if link.get_attribute('src') is not None else link.get_attribute('href')
        final.append(ref)
    return final

url = "https://www.electronic-festivals.com/event/i-am-hardstyle-germany" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.media-youtube-player'))
final = []

try:
    links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[href*=youtube] , [src*=youtube]")))
    addItems(links, final)
except:
    pass
finally:
    driver.switch_to.default_content()

links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[href*=youtube] , [src*=youtube]')
addItems(links, final)

for link in set(final):
    print(link)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the iframe tag. I did not use selenium for it though. The code that worked was: youtube_link = soup.find('iframe')['src'] (I'm sorry for the constant editing. I'm not used to asking questions here). Thanks again!

Comment: @adomzy You should post the solution so we can see your nifty work. I too don't know what the heck Selenium is or what or why use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by scraping downloading, try

```
pip install youtube-dl
```

in your shell.

Comment: Youtube-dl will download a single video, given you supply the url.  It will not scrape a url page and give back a list of urls.

Answer (score 0):

you better use tools instead, youtube frontend or code will change, so better use command link tools, or apis or https://onlinetool.app/ext/youtube_dl