# scraping youtube website using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image]

i am scraping youtube search results using the following code :

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=python"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
for each in soup.find_all("a", class_="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer"):
    print(each.get('href'))
```

but it is returning nothing . what is wrong with this code?

Comment: not requests neither BeautifulSoup process JavaScripts on that site. You will need a different solution, where you have to not only download the base html, but execute javascripts and wait for dynamic content. You could start with Selenium or scrapy with scrapy-splash

Comment: There is javascript involved and beautiful soup does not execute it. You have to use something like `selenium` to extract data from youtube. 

Instead check out `youtube-dl` to search / extract / download data from youtube.

Comment: Duplicate of [Scraping YouTube links from a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973419/scraping-youtube-links-from-a-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

BeatifulSoup is not the right tool for Youtube **scraping**_ - Youtube is generating a lot of content using JavaScript.

You can easily test it:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>>> url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=python"
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
>>> soup.find_all("a")
[<a href="//www.youtube.com/yt/about/en-GB/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">About</a>, <a href="//www.youtube.com/yt/press/en-GB/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Press</a>, <a href="//www.youtube.com/yt/copyright/en-GB/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Copyright</a>, <a href="/t/contact_us" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Contact us</a>, <a href="//www.youtube.com/yt/creators/en-GB/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Creators</a>, <a href="//www.youtube.com/yt/advertise/en-GB/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Advertise</a>, <a href="//www.youtube.com/yt/dev/en-GB/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Developers</a>, <a href="/t/terms" slot="guide-links-secondary" style="display: none;">Terms</a>, <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en-GB/policies/privacy/" slot="guide-links-secondary" style="display: none;">Privacy</a>, <a href="//www.youtube.com/yt/policyandsafety/en-GB/" slot="guide-links-secondary" style="display: none;">Policy and Safety</a>, <a href="/new" slot="guide-links-secondary" style="display: none;">Test new features</a>]
```

(pay attention there's that links you see on the screenshot are not present in the list)

You need to use another solution for that - Selenium might be a good choice. Please have at look at this thread for details [Fetch all href link using selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759787/fetch-all-href-link-using-selenium-in-python)