# Web Scraping Youtube search results with Python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

```
    def url_search(self, search_string, max_search):
        textToSearch = search_string
        query = urllib.parse.quote(textToSearch)
        url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        html = response.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        i = 1
        for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}):
            if len(self.dict) < max_search:
                self.dict[i] = 'https://www.youtube.com' + vid['href']
                i += 1
            else:
                break
```

I am trying to get the video href's from the youtube search results page using BS4
I believe the issue with this is that `soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}):` is being returned as None. I'm not quite sure. Help with this issue or maybe alternative methods and ideas would he appreciated.

Comment: can you add a test call to your function to make this a minimally, reproducable example

Comment: If the findAll entry is returning none it would indicate it hasn't found anything, also please rename to bs4 findAll returns none

Comment: Also adjust your code sample to be a single stand alone function so ppl can copy and paste it into their debugging environments to more easily help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping YouTube links from a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973419/scraping-youtube-links-from-a-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

Youtube generates a lot of the content on its page using javascript it is unlikely you will get what you want from beautiful soup. You will need to use selenium or another javascript enabled parser.

Note this doesn't mean bs4 is bad it's very good for sites that aren't so heavy with javascript and is faster than selenium in these cases.

For more info see: [Scraping YouTube links from a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973419/scraping-youtube-links-from-a-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out YouTube generates the search results page using JavaScript. Instead of using bs4 I found an alternative method using the official YouTube API. In my case using the YouTube API was much simpler.

For more info regarding YouTube API see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3